# CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED error while training StyleGan

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I downloaded stylegan code from https://github.com/NVlabs/stylegan and want to train it with my dataset. I am working on an ubuntu machine (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS) and

```
 python train.py
```

gives an error, says:

```
 2020-01-26 23:30:27.115726: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:329] Could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
 2020-01-26 23:30:27.115811: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:337] Possibly insufficient driver version: 430.50.0
```

here is the outputs of my cuda,cudnn and pip list:

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2018 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sat_Aug_25_21:08:01_CDT_2018
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.0, V10.0.130

$nvidia-smi
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 430.50       Driver Version: 430.50       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 2060    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 42%   37C    P8    14W / 170W |    529MiB /  5931MiB |      2%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1100      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           245MiB |
|    0      1578      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         149MiB |
|    0      2179      G   ...quest-channel-token=1359353350696709871   132MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

$dpkg -l | grep -i cudnn
ii  libcudnn7 7.6.5.32-1+cuda10.2       amd64        cuDNN runtime libraries
ii  libcudnn7-dev 7.6.5.32-1+cuda10.2   amd64        cuDNN development libraries and headers

$pip list

absl-py (0.9.0)
astor (0.8.1)
bleach (1.5.0)
certifi (2019.11.28)
chardet (3.0.4)
gast (0.3.3)
google-pasta (0.1.8)
grpcio (1.26.0)
h5py (2.10.0)
html5lib (0.9999999)
idna (2.8)
Keras-Applications (1.0.8)
Keras-Preprocessing (1.1.0)
Markdown (3.1.1)
mock (3.0.5)
numpy (1.18.1)
opencv-python (4.1.0.25)
Pillow (6.1.0)
pip (9.0.1)
pkg-resources (0.0.0)
protobuf (3.11.2)
requests (2.22.0)
scipy (1.2.0)
setuptools (45.1.0)
six (1.14.0)
tensorboard (1.14.0)
tensorflow-estimator (1.14.0)
tensorflow-gpu (1.14.0)
termcolor (1.1.0)
tqdm (4.32.2)
urllib3 (1.25.7)
Werkzeug (0.16.0)
wheel (0.33.6)
wrapt (1.11.2)
absl-py (0.9.0)
astor (0.8.1)
bleach (1.5.0)
certifi (2019.11.28)
chardet (3.0.4)
gast (0.3.3)
google-pasta (0.1.8)
grpcio (1.26.0)
h5py (2.10.0)
html5lib (0.9999999)
idna (2.8)
Keras-Applications (1.0.8)
Keras-Preprocessing (1.1.0)
Markdown (3.1.1)
mock (3.0.5)
numpy (1.18.1)
opencv-python (4.1.0.25)
Pillow (6.1.0)
pip (9.0.1)
pkg-resources (0.0.0)
protobuf (3.11.2)
requests (2.22.0)
scipy (1.2.0)
setuptools (45.1.0)
six (1.14.0)
tensorboard (1.14.0)
tensorflow-estimator (1.14.0)
tensorflow-gpu (1.14.0)
termcolor (1.1.0)
tqdm (4.32.2)
urllib3 (1.25.7)
Werkzeug (0.16.0)
wheel (0.33.6)
wrapt (1.11.2)
```

Is there any one knows a specific version of these tools with which I can run stylegan?

Comment: Hello, have you tried upgrading your apt packages, especially `cuda-drivers`? Are there any packages that are hold back from upgrading?

Comment: Hş @ThanosParavantis, I just did what you told and it worked. Thank you so much for the suggestion. I was thinking the problem occurs because of the code I am working on. How I updated is: firstly I removed the older ones with 
rm -f /usr/include/cudnn.h
rm -f /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*libcudnn*
rm -f /usr/local/cuda-*/lib64/*libcudnn*
after that, I followed the instructions on https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html and copy the files to the appropriate places as described in the link above.

Comment: Awesome! Glad this worked out for you. I had the same issue and for some reason apt couldn't update `cuda-drivers` so I had to manually install the updated version, hence the versioning issues with Tensorflow. Odd stuff.

Comment: absolutely, I forgot to tell. After updating cudnn, TensorFlow complained and I updated it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing the solution here (Answer Section), even though it is present in the Comment Section, for the benefit of the community.

First need to remove all cuDNN files

```
rm -f /usr/include/cudnn.h 
rm -f /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*libcudnn* 
rm -f /usr/local/cuda-/lib64/*libcudnn
```

Now extract new cuDNN from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download)

In order to download cuDNN, ensure you are registered for the [NVIDIA Developer Program](https://developer.nvidia.com/developer-program).

1. Go to: [NVIDIA cuDNN home page](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn).
2. Click Download.
3. Complete the short survey and click Submit.
4. Accept the Terms and Conditions. A list of available download versions of cuDNN displays.
5. Select the cuDNN version you want to install. A list of available resources displays.

Please check Tested build configurations for Tensorflow GPU [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu)

[image]

Copy the following files into the CUDA Toolkit directory, and change the file permissions

```
sudo cp cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include
sudo cp cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64
sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*
```

For more detaila please refer cuDNN Installation Guide [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/cudnn-install/index.html)

***Note***: After updating cuDNN, if TensorFlow complained then update Tensorflow accordingly